# Intermittent "too many open files" when including/requiring PHP scripts

Tags: php, require

On my development box (thank goodness it's not happening in production—that I know of—yet), as I'm working on a PHP site, I get this occasional error:

> Warning:
>   require_once(*filename.php*): failed
>   to open stream: Too many open files in
>   *path*/functions.php on line 502
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '*filename.php*'
>   (include_path='/my/include/path') in
>   *path*/functions.php on line 502

Line 502 of functions.php is my "autoload" function which automatically requires PHP files containing classes I use:

```
function autoload($className)
{
    require_once $className . ".php";   // <-- Line 502
}
```

By an "occasional" error, I mean that it'll work fine for about a day of development, then when I first see this, I can refresh the page and it'll be okay again, then refreshing gives me the same error. This happens just a few times before it starts to show it every time. And sometimes the name of the file it's requiring (I have a script split out into several PHP files) is different... it's not always the first or last or middle files that it bombs on.

Restarting php-fpm seems to solve the symptoms, but not the problem in the long run.

I'm running PHP 5.5.3 on my Mac (OS X 10.8) with nginx 1.4.2 via php-fpm.

Running `lsof | grep php-fpm | wc -l` tells me that php-fpm has **824** files open. When I examined the actual output, I saw that, along with some `.so` and `.dylib` files, the vast majority of lines were like this:

```
php-fpm    4093 myuser  69u   unix 0x45bc1a64810eb32b    0t0   ->(none)
```

The segment "69u" and the 0x45bc1a6481... number are different on each row. What could this mean? Is this the problem? (`ulimit` is "unlimited")

Incidentally (though perhaps un-related), there's also one or two of these:

```
php-fpm  4093 myuser  8u  IPv4 0x45bc1a646b0f97b3   0t0   TCP 192.168.1.2:59611->rest.nexmo.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

(I have some pages which use HttpRequest (PECL libraries) to call out to the Nexmo API. Are these not being closed properly or something? How can I crack down on those?)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set php-fpm (they're set to infinite by default) to more appropriate values on your needs.

For example:

```
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s
```

Maybe, set this too if your app works with lots of files:

```
rlimit_files = 1024
```